# Emoji module Python

Tags: python, emoji

I'm trying to make a rock/paper/scissors game in Python and I want to print some emojis representing "rock", "paper" and "scissors".
I downloaded emoji module and then I imported it in my code.
However, when I try to use the function and write the emoji (eg: :fist:), it prints exactly ":fist:" and not a fist emoji. I wanted to print three emojis, ":fist:", ":v:" and ":raised_hand:", but only ":raised_hand:" works.

I've tried to change emojis but some work and some don't.

#### Here's my code:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize(":fist:"))
print(emoji.emojize(":v:"))
print(emoji.emojize(":raised_hand:"))
```

I hope you can help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `use_aliases=True` to get emojis from `:fist:` and `:v:`:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize(":fist:", use_aliases=True))
print(emoji.emojize(":v:", use_aliases=True))
print(emoji.emojize(":raised_hand:"))
```

Output:

```
✊
✌
✋
```

`:fist:` is an alias for `:raised_fist:` and `:v:` is an alias for `:victory_hand:` so you can also use these full names:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize(":raised_fist:"))
print(emoji.emojize(":victory_hand:"))
print(emoji.emojize(":raised_hand:"))
```

Output will be the same.